# How to navigate as per MVVM architecture in Xamarin.Forms without using any frameworks like PRISM or any Navigation Service?

Tags: generics, mvvm, xamarin.forms, navigation, func

I have a **LoginPage.xaml** that inherits **PageBase.xaml**. **LoginViewModel** is the **ViewModel** for **LoginPage** and it inherits **BaseViewModel**. **BaseViewModel** has **Func** delegate defined - **OnModalNavigationRequest** which is subscribed by **PageBase** in it's **OnAppearing** method and implementation is provided in **HandleModalNavigationRequest** method. When **Login Button** is clicked on **LoginPage.xaml**, **OnSubmit** method of **LoginViewModel**, bound through command is invoked which, on successful authentication, calls **NavigateToModal** method of **BaseViewModel**. **NavigateToModel** method of **BaseViewModel** invokes **HandleModalNavigationRequest** method of **PageBase** on **Func** delegate **OnModalNavigationRequest** after checking if it is not **null**.

My problem is **OnModalNavigationRequest** is **always** coming as **null**, indicating that there is no subscriber to it. That means **OnAppearing** method of **PageBase** is not getting called which implies that **PageBase** is not getting instantiated. How to resolve this issue?

I'm posting the code of sequence of events that is taking place:

Disclaimer: Code help has been taken from [here](http://www.fabiocozzolino.eu/simple-approach-to-navigation-with-Model-View-ViewModel-in-Xamarin-Forms/)

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
        var properties = Current.Properties;

        if (properties.ContainsKey("Username"))
        {
            if (properties["Username"] != null)
            {
                var loggedInUser = (string)properties["Username"];
                MainPage = new MainPage();
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new LoginPage();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new LoginPage();
        }
    }
```

**IView**

```
public interface IView
{
}

public interface IView<TViewModel> : IView where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    TViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

**BaseViewModel**

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       private string title;
       public string Title
       {
         get { return GetProperty<string>("title"); }
         set { SetProperty(value, "title"); }
       }

       protected bool SetProperty<T>(T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
       {
         if (!properties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
         {
            properties.Add(propertyName, default(T));
         }

         var oldValue = GetProperty<T>(propertyName);
         if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(oldValue, value))
            return false;

         properties[propertyName] = value;
         onChanged?.Invoke();
         OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
         return true;
       }

       protected T GetProperty<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
         if (!properties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
         {
            return default(T);
         }
         else
         {
            return (T)properties[propertyName];
         }
       }

       public Func<BaseViewModel, Task> OnModalNavigationRequest { get; set; }

       public async Task NavigateToModal<TViewModel>(TViewModel targetViewModel) where TViewModel : BaseViewModel
      {
        await OnModalNavigationRequest?.Invoke(targetViewModel);
      }
    }
```

**ViewResolver**

```
    internal static class ViewResolver
    {
        public static Page GetViewFor<TargetViewModel>(TargetViewModel targetViewModel) where 
TargetViewModel : BaseViewModel, new()
        {
            var targetViewName = targetViewModel.GetType().Name.Replace("ViewModel", "Page");
            var definedTypes = targetViewModel.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes;
            var targetType = definedTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == targetViewName);
            return Activator.CreateInstance(targetType.AsType()) as Page;
        }
    }
```

**PageBase.xaml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="IPMS.Views.Shared.PageBase">
    </ContentPage>
```

**PageBase.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class PageBase<TViewModel> : ContentPage, IView<TViewModel> where TViewModel : BaseViewModel, new()
   {
    public TViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(BindingContextProperty) as TViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BindingContextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #region <Events>

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        ViewModel.OnModalNavigationRequest = HandleModalNavigationRequest;
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        ViewModel.OnModalNavigationRequest = null;
    }
    #endregion

    async Task HandleModalNavigationRequest(BaseViewModel targetViewModel)
    {
        var targetView = ViewResolver.GetViewFor(targetViewModel);
        targetView.BindingContext = targetViewModel;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(targetView));
    }
}
```

**LoginPage.xaml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <views:PageBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:IPMS.Views.Shared;assembly=IPMS"
         x:Class="IPMS.Views.Shared.LoginPage"
         Title="{Binding Title}">

         <ContentPage.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary>
             // Resources goes here
           </ResourceDictionary>
         </ContentPage.Resources>

         <ContentPage.Content>
           <StackLayout>
                <Button Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Text="Login" TextColor="White"  
                FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
         </ContentPage.Content>
    </views:PageBase>
```

**LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class LoginPage : PageBase
    {
        LoginViewModel ViewModel => BindingContext as LoginViewModel;

        public LoginPage() : base()
        {
            BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**LoginViewModel.cs**

```
        public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
            public Command SubmitCommand { protected set; get; }

            public LoginViewModel() : base()
            {
                Title = "Login";
                SubmitCommand = new Command(async () => await OnSubmit());
            }

            public async Task OnSubmit()
            {
                await NavigateToModal<ItemsViewModel>(new ItemsViewModel());
            }
        }
```

Comment: ,According to article, I find author provide simple, so do you try to author's sample?

Comment: Yes but the sample didn't include pages which inherited from **PageBase.xaml** and this is where I faced challenge as at some links, it was given that we cannot inherit XAML and as I've just started with Xamarin, I was not aware of what x:TypeArguments does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by

1. Adding x:TypeArguments in **LoginPage.xaml** as shown below:

   ```
   <views:PageBase xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:IPMS.Views.Shared;assembly=IPMS"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:IPMS.ViewModels.Shared;assembly=IPMS"
        x:Class="IPMS.Views.Shared.LoginPage"
        x:TypeArguments="ViewModel:LoginViewModel"
        BackgroundImageSource="loginbg.9.jpg"
        Title="{Binding Title}">
   </views:PageBase>
   ```
2. Changing the **LoginPage.xaml.cs** as shown below:

   ```
   public partial class LoginPage : PageBase<LoginViewModel>
   {
       public LoginPage() : base()
       {
           BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();

           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, so please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.